# Annotate count of FK of FK

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I have a "Team" class, a "Game" class, a "Player" class and a "Goal" class.

How can I annotate the count of "goals" for each "Team" considering that I have the following structure:

```
class Team(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('Team name', max_length=255)

class Game(models.Model):
    team1 = models.ForeignKey(Team, verbose_name = 'Team 1')
    team2 = models.ForeignKey(Team, verbose_name = 'Team 2')

class Player(models.Model):
    team = models.ForeignKey(Team, verbose_name = 'Team')

class Goal(models.Model):
    player = models.ForeignKey(Player, verbose_name = 'Player')
    game = models.ForeignKey(Game, verbose_name = 'Game')
```

What I have tried so far:

```
Team.objects.annotate(nr_goals=Count('goal')).order_by('nr_goals')
```

I also have the possibility to change my models if needed.

Comment: I suggest adding a foreign key to Team in Goal. That way you can also keep track of players who score own goals (since the Goal would be counted for Team A while the player is in Team B)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are already on the right path. Try:

```
Team.objects.annotate(nr_goals=Count('game__goal')).order_by('nr_goals')
```

You can also use the `Player` model relation.

```
Team.objects.annotate(nr_goals=Count('player__goal')).order_by('nr_goals')
```

Comment: assuming that I have a "is_goalkeeper" boolean field on my player model, how could I annotate the number of goals each goalkeeper player has taken?

Comment: That's what I got so far:
Player.objects.filter(team=form.cleaned_data['team']).annotate(num_gols=Count('goal', filter=((Q(goal__game__team1=team) || Q(goal__game__team2=team)) & goal__player_team__notin=team)).exclude(is_goalkeeper=False)

Comment: Maybe something like `Player.objects.filter(is_goalkeeper=True).annotate(goals=Count('goal'))`?